# Firestore: How to include doc.id in doc.data() while mapping?

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-firestore

I want to bind my data to the below HTML table:

```
<table id="tableAccounts">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Deposit / Credit Limit</th>
                <th>Date Joined</th>
                <th>Total Course</th>
                <th>UPV Cost</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="account in accounts">
                <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.AccStatus }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.AccName }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.Deposit }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.DateJoined }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.TotalCourse }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.UpvCost }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So I have the following code in my AngularJS controller:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

        db.collection("Accounts").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                $scope.accounts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
```

But the above code doesn't include the `doc.id` in `doc.data()` while performing mapping. How can I include the `doc.id` in this scenario so that it can bind to the `Code` column of my HTML table?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, using the spread operator, whose behavior is similar to `Object.assign()`, except that it doesn't trigger setters, nor mutate any object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```
querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id:doc.id}))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `doc.id` you have to use `snapshotChanges()` in your code like this:

```
db.collection("Accounts").snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
  });
});
```

Comment: Is that 3 dots (`...data`) part of the coding syntax also?

Comment: Yes it is. With the three dots you make clear to return a new data object as the one you declare with ‘const data’

Comment: So later how do I assign the returned data to my `$scope.accounts`? Can I do something like `$scope.accounts = db.collection("Accounts").snapshotChanges().map(actions => {...`?

Comment: I edited my post. Your `Accounts` model does have an `id` field right? So I removed the `as Account`. That way you should be able to assign to your list of `Accounts`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but how about the other question in the comment? How do I assign the returned data to my `$scope.accounts`?

Comment: I get an error: `TypeError: db.collection(...).snapshotChanges is not a function`.

Comment: Can you edit in your post how you implement it? And actually with your `$scope.accounts` should work I guess. Didn't worked with AngularJS before. But what you should get as a return have to be a list of objects with the same fields as in your `Accounts` model.

Comment: I shouldn't edit my question by including your answer, that will be very confusing. But I did give the sample code on how I implement it in my original method. I need to assign the returned data to the `$scope.accounts` or else AngularJS won't bind with the HTML table.

Comment: Yeah you should assign it to `$scope.accounts`. I forgot the "I" before "Didn't worked with..." in my comment before. Think that was confusing. And I tried to move this conversation to a chat, but think the chat.stackoverflow.com site is down.

Comment: Nope, unable to, check out my [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718431/firestore-snapshotchanges-is-not-a-function).

Comment: @AntonioOoi you said that you got an error saying `map is not defined`. Did you import map like this: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` ?