# Firestore: snapshotChanges is not a function

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

In reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710997/firestore-how-to-include-doc-id-in-doc-data-while-mapping), I hit a problem where it says `snapshotChanges is not a function`:

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).snapshotChanges is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (index.js:139)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5156)
    at angular.js:11719
    at Object.link (angular-route.js:1251)
    at angular.js:1388
    at Ba (angular.js:11266)
    at p (angular.js:10585)
    at g (angular.js:9832)
    at angular.js:9697
    at angular.js:10111 "<ng-view autoscroll="true" class="ng-scope">"
```

Below is my code:
(Note that with or without `pipe()` will also hit the same error too.)

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

        $scope.accounts = db.collection("Accounts").snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
            });
        }));
```

On my SPA `index.html`, I have the following references defined:

```
<script defer src="/__/firebase/6.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.4.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.4.1/firebase-storage.js"></script> -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  <!-- AngularFire -->
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

May I know why this error (`snapshotChanges is not a function`) still appear? I need it [to include the `doc.id` in my mapping result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710997/firestore-how-to-include-doc-id-in-doc-data-while-mapping), thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the plain JavaScript SDK to query Firestore, and you want to attach a listener to a Query, you should be using [onSnapshot()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#on-snapshot) for that.

If you want to use the AngularFire API instead and use [snapshotChanges](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges), that's going to require a going through its own API (see the link), which is different than the plain JavaScript SDK.

Comment: But now it says `map is not defined`. How can I achieve the same result by using `onSnapshot()`?

Comment: I think you might want to review the AngularFire documentation I linked to in order to understand how to use its APIs.  Don't use the plain JavaScript documentation if you want to use snapshotChanges and the other Angular APIs.  They work differently.