# Unable to use interface with AngularFirebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, casting

While trying to create a shopping cart in angular, I've run into type issues regarding my components and services. My service currently returns `AngularFireList<{}>` and though I can change its type, doing so has side-effects in other methods and inside of my component. I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to allow my current interface to become the type.

I've tried to cast the type as `Observable<ProdInterface>` which again, solves one issue while bringing in another.

My current interface is:

```js
export interface ProdInterface {
    $key:string;
    color_way: string;
    name: string;
    id: number;
    description: string;
    photo:string;
    price:number;
    qty:number;
}
```

I'm looking to implement this method so that I can keep the `$key` which will allow me to find an item in my firebase database:

```js
  async addToCart(product: ProdInterface){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCart();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.$key);
    item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
       item$.update({ product: product, 
                      quantity: (item.payload.exportVal().quantity || 0) + 1 });
    });
}
```

Getting all of my products from my firebase database returns an `Observable<{}>` type which does not have `$key` attribute I need for my `addToCart` method

```js
  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Which then means when using the method the wrong type is returned:

```js
   this.products$ =  this.productService.getAll();
```

My end goal is such that I can map the current returned type of `getAll()` to my `ProdInterface` so that I can then use it inside of my `addToCart` method.

I would appreciate any guidance in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `$key` representing your document's id in your firebase db?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Yes it is

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710997/firestore-how-to-include-doc-id-in-doc-data-while-mapping/57711170#57711170

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Thanks for the link, and this is a step in the right direction -- however I'm using the realtime database not firestore for the project. And it seems that the properties listed are different

Comment: I guess you already read the AngularFire docs? https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#angularfireaction---action-based-api

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Sure have, might be tired eyes at this point but I'm having a hard time connecting the dots based on the docs too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198753/discussion-between-joel-carter-and-constantin-beer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the example from the Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#for-each) you could try this:

```
this.product$ = db.ref("products").orderByKey()
                  .once("value")
                  .pipe(
                  .map(snapshot => {
                      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot) {
                      var key = childSnapshot.key
                      var childData = childSnapshot.val()
                      return {key, ...childData} 
                      }
                   }));
```

Comment: I have a version of this, but slightly different. I'm working on fixing a bug when the addToCart button is clicked now