# Interface logs as undefined though the products gathered from service call display on page

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, interface, angularfire5

This question is a follow-up to a previous question posted here -- [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734977/unable-to-use-interface-with-angularfirebase/57735674#57735674)

I'm attempting to place data into a firebase database (Specifically the realtime database) and I've written a service that will get all of my current products, which would then be used inside of a method to create a shopping cart.

However, my service continues to return back an undefined result though I can get and display products on the view.

I've attempted to place my data into an Interface manually but each time I log to the console I get `undefined`.

This service method is being used to retrieve the products from the firebase database:

```js
getAll() {
    this.itemRef = this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(changes => {
            return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
        })
    );
    return this.itemRef;
}
```

The below code snippet displays what I have tried to accomplish inside of my component.

```js
products$: Observable<ProdInterface>;
prodLook: ProdInterface[]

this.products$ = this.productService.getAll();

this.productService.getAll().subscribe(data =>
    this.prodLook = [{
        color_way: data.color_way,
        description: data.description,
        $key: data.key,
        name: data.name,
        photo: data.photo,
        price: data.price,
        qty: data.qty
    }]
)
```

The goal from the above snippet is to pass `products$` into this method:

```js
//product returns undefined
async addToCart(product: ProdInterface, change: number) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCart();
    debugger
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.$key);
    item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {

        if (item.payload.exists()) {
            let quantity = item.payload.exportVal().quantity + change;
            if (quantity === 0) item$.remove();
            else
                item$.update({
                    product: item.payload.exportVal(),
                    quantity: quantity
                });
        } else {
            item$.set({ product: item.payload.exportVal(), quantity: 1 });
        }
    })
}
```

Edit: HTML used to bind to `addToCart`

```
<div *ngIf='products$'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let product of products$ | async">
      <mdb-card>
        <!--Card image-->
        <mdb-card-img [src]="product.photo" alt="Card image cap"></mdb-card-img>
        <!--Card content-->
        <mdb-card-body>

          <!--Title-->
          <mdb-card-title>
            <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
          </mdb-card-title>

          <!--Text-->
          <mdb-card-text> 
            {{product.description}}
          </mdb-card-text>
          <span> 
            <mdb-card-text>{{product.price}}</mdb-card-text>
          </span>

        <button (click)="addToCartProd()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add To Cart</button>
        </mdb-card-body>
      </mdb-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The addToCartProd method used in tandem with the HTML

```js
  // addToCartProd(){
  //   this.cartService.addToCart(this.products$,1)
  //   console.log(this.products$)
  // }
```

My goal for this code is to attach `addToCart` to a button on the view and send the correct product to the database based on it's key. The current implementation sends `undefined` to the database, which is the cause of confusion because the products display on the page using the same `getAll()` method.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the html that is binding to `addToCard(..)`?

Comment: @JasonWhite I've added the HTML used to bind to the `addToCart` method

Comment: In your template you're not passing the product to `addToCart`.  Try `<button (click)="addToCart(product)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add To Cart</button>`

Comment: Hey @JasonWhite I've added a new edit which is the full implementation of the code. ` addToCartProd` actually calls the `addToCart` method from the `productService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You template should pass the `product` from the `*ngFor` to the `addToCardProd()`.  You template and method should look like something below.

#### products.component.html

```
<div *ngIf='products$'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let product of products$ | async">
      <mdb-card>
        ...
        <button (click)="addToCartProd(product)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add To Cart</button>
        </mdb-card-body>
      </mdb-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### products.component.ts

```
addToCartProd(product: ProdInterface){
  this.cartService.addToCart(product,1)
  console.log(products$)
}
```

Comment: Though the code solution works, it's still not yielding the result I'm looking for. Firebase still shows `/shopping-carts/cartId/items/undefined`

Comment: After some more searching and debugging, I figured out that I wasn't passing my product object to the service which rendered it as `undefined`. After passing it from the view to the service...everything works like a charm!! Thanks!

Comment: @JoelCarter glad you got it figure out.

Comment: Couldn't have done it without ya. consider this a team effort :)